# jQuery - How to recursively loop over an object's nested properties?

Tags: jquery

Is there are a way to recursively loop over all the nested properties of a JS/jQuery object?

For example, given this object

```
var x = {
    'name': 'a',
    'level': 1,
    'children': [{
        'name': 'b',
        'level': 2,
        'children': [{
            'name': 'c',
            'level': 3,
            'children': [{
            ...
            }]
        }]},
        ...
    }]
}
```

how could I loop over the objects named 'a' and their children, 'b' and their children, 'c' and their children, ad infinitum?

Comment: What is your intend for this function? List all the child objects, count them?

Comment: 10 print "use recursion"; 20 goto 10

Comment: check children.lenght if >0 , call your function recursively.

Comment: @KyorCode The purpose of the function is to do something on a property if it meets certain conditions. It could easily be done if the object structure is known beforehand but as it is, the object structure is variable.

Comment: @YograjGupta The 'children' property is just an example. I actually do not know which of the properties are object themselves.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A recursive approach seems best, something like this:

```
function recursiveIteration(object) {
    for (var property in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (typeof object[property] == "object"){
                recursiveIteration(object[property]);
            }else{
                //found a property which is not an object, check for your conditions here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[This is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L24Sd/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not well formatted but you can "visit" each item as below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x = {
                "name": "a",
                "level": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "b",
                        "level": 2,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "c",
                                "level": 3,
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "sss": 23
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            };

         function visit(obj){
            for(var prop in obj){
                if(typeof(obj[prop]) == 'object'){
                    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) == '[object Array]'){
                        for(var i = 0; i < obj[prop].length; i++){
                            document.write("<br />the element " + prop + " (array) was visited");
                            visit(obj[prop][i]);                                
                        }
                    }else{
                        document.write("<br />the element " + prop + " (object) was visited");
                        visit(obj[prop]);
                    }
                }else{
                    document.write("<br />the element " + prop + " = " + obj[prop] + " was visited");
                }
            }
        }

        visit(x);

    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: `typeof array === "object'` so you can't test if it's an array that way.

Comment: @jfriend00 you're right. This make my answer not so useful and I think I'll remove it.

Comment: You don't have to remove it - just fix it: http://ajaxian.com/archives/isarray-why-is-it-so-bloody-hard-to-get-right

Answer (score 1):

I was originally looking for a way to search a javascript object recursively and I found this post very helpful, in particular Jeroen Moons's answer. I have tweaked it to provide a return object. Input is **object** to search and a **{key:value}** object (needle).

```
function searchObject(object, keyvalue){
    var found = false;
    for (var property in object){
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)){
            if (typeof object[property] == 'object'){
                found = searchObject(object[property], keyvalue);
                if (found)
                    return found;
            }else{
                key = Object.keys(keyvalue)[0];
                if (property == key && object[key] == keyvalue[key]){
                    console.log('searchObject ' + keyvalue[key] + ' found');
                    return object;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = {
    'name': 'a',
    'level': 1,
    'children': [{
        'name': 'b',
        'level' : 2,
        'children' : [{
            'name': 'c',
            'level' : 3,
            'children' : [{
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        'name': 'b2',
        'level' : 2,
        'children' : [{
            'name': 'c2',
            'level' : 3,
            'children' : [{
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
var step = x;
do {
    if (step instanceof Array){
        for (i=0; i < step.length; i++) {
            callback(step[i]);
        }
    }
    else {
        callback(step);
    }
    step = step.children != undefined ? step.children : null;
} while (step);

function callback (element) {
    console.log(element);
}
```

as long as the structure does not change, you can go down like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function iterate(obj){
    for(var key in obj)
    {
        if(typeof(obj["key"]) == "object"){
            iterate(obj["key"]);
        }
        else{
            console.log(key + ": " + obj["key"];
        }
    }

}
```