# Reading object from success function of $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have following ajax function..

```
         $.ajax({
                url: './sales/cat/salesCat'
              , target: null
              , type: "get"
              , dataType: "json"
              , data: {

                  locale: LOCALE
              }
              , success: function (object) {
                  $.each(object, function (key, value) {
                      alert(key + ":" + value);
                  })
              }
         });
```

It returns following output

```
 {
  "success": true,
  "totalCount": 2,
  "data": [
    {
      "East Division": "Yearly Sales"
      "West Division": "Yearly Sales"
    }
  ]
}
```

Problem is I am trying to read the returned values to use it. When Success function executes and in my alert I get alert message

```
         data:[object Object]
```

Please let me know how to correct the

```
          $.each(object, function (key, value) {
                  alert(key + ":" + value);
              })
```

So alert can display for example  East Division:Yearly Sales 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't use `alert` to debug code, use `console.log`. `[object Object]` is a stringified object, as `alert` only takes strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - How to recursively loop over an object's nested properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295494/jquery-how-to-recursively-loop-over-an-objects-nested-properties)

Comment: first of all you missed one comma, second this happens because it gets stuck at data array.

Comment: @Blazeonger! I already searched the Stackoverflow this is not what my question is. It is not a duplicate post. I guess if you want to far fetch you can say anything is duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when using `alert()` to output an object the object gets converted to a string. An object as a string is "[object Object]".

Instead you should use `console.log()` to output the object to your browser's [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

```
var data = { key: "value" };
data.toString(); // "[object Object]"
data; // Object { key: "value" }
```

The other problem you have is that your `data` response is missing a `,` and is thus invalid:

```
"data": [
    {
      "East Division": "Yearly Sales" // <--- No comma
      "West Division": "Yearly Sales"
    }
]
```

This will throw:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Thanks for the observation and comment. I forgot to add it while copying in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The data you're getting back *is* an object, hence your `data:[object Object]` response in the alert.

To debug, use `console.log()` instead and look in your browser console (Chrome: F12 debug tools, for example).

If you wanted to get the first value of your data object in this case, you can reference it one of two ways:

```
data["East Division"]
```

Or

```
data[0]
```

You can also use recursion to do this, see how to [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript)

Comment: I think he wants a way to recursively iterate over object, not to reference each one. +1 for you support

Answer (score 0):

You can translate it to a JSON string (for debugging obviously):

```
alert(JSON.stringify(object));
```