# how to build javascript object dynamically with array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, javascript-objects

I need to create the object property from array values and assign some values to that for example

```
var main_obj = {};
var dynamic_array = ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"];
```

From `dynamic_array` I need to create `main_obj` like:

```
main_obj[value1][value2][value3] = some_value;
```

Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean: `main_obj[dynamic_array[0]]` etc... ?

Comment: Well, if it so, you can use something weird like [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/oa1dgg51/).

Comment: where are values coming from? This question is really lacking in detail

Comment: @charlietfl Am getting the values at run-time and push into the dynamic_array

Comment: actually my main_obj = {"value1":{"value2":{"value3":}}} is like this what i need to do is i need to parse through until value3 and add the new object, the dynamic_array is a reference for how long i need to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i parse through the object recursively rather than building that [jQuery - How to recursively loop over an object's nested properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295494/jquery-how-to-recursively-loop-over-an-objects-nested-properties)

```
    function recursiveIteration(main_obj) {
        for (var property in main_obj) {
            if (property == value3)
            {
                main_obj[property] = {"value4":test};
            }
            else
            {
                recursiveIteration(main_obj[property]);
            }
        }
    }
    recursiveIteration(main_obj);
```

Comment: That's not an absolute solution, only works with fixed property, should not be preferred to other (more correct) suggested ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamic_array.forEach(function(prop){
   main_obj[prop] = some_value;  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to interpretate your question, this may be a solution to what you are looking for:

```
function createNestedProperties(obj, array, value) {
    var result = {};
    var result_tmp = obj;
    var i = 0;
    while (i < array.length) {
        if (i < (array.length - 1))
            result_tmp[array[i]] = {};
        else
            result_tmp[array[i]] = value;
        result_tmp = result_tmp[array[i]];
        i++;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

used this way:

```
var main_obj = {"value1":{"value2":{"value3":{}}}};
var dynamic_array = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];

main_obj = createNestedProperties(main_obj, dynamic_array, {"value_Z":"new value"});
```

Resulting object:

```
{"value1":{"value2":{"value3":{"value_Z":"new value"}}}}
```

This function would override existing properties in `main_obj` if already there.

Comment: @Troy I have slightly updated the above code, using that function you will be able to set a new {...} object to "value3" property (possibly overriding an existing value if present).

Answer (score 0):

this is another way

```
var dynamic_array = ["value1","value2","value3"];
var value = 'your value';

function createobj(dynamic_array,value){
    var count = dynamic_array.length;
    var text= '';
    var ended = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
      text += '{"'+dynamic_array[i]+'":';
      ended +='}';
    }
    text += '"'+value+'"'+ended;
    return JSON.parse(text);
}
console.log(createobj(dynamic_array,value));
```

Comment: actually my main_obj = {"value1":{"value2":{"value3":}}} is like this what i need to do is i need to parse through until value3 and add the new object, the dynamic_array is a reference for how long i need to parse. thanks

Comment: actually my main_obj = {"value1":{"value2":{"value3":}}} is like this what i need to do is i need to parse through until value3 and add the new object, the dynamic_array is a reference for how long i need to parse.